# Django-rest-API Authorization with react

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I work with react and Django-rest-framework, so I have an API for generate access token and

refresh token  and store that access token in cookies with **httponly set to true**  for security

but I am trying this:

> when a user logs in the log in API return the access token and store
> in cookies I need to request the server if this user is authorized but
> when I do that **with Credentials set to true**

the request send the cookies with request but not generate authorized header for the API

> here the API test on [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa2Dk.png)
>
> here [user authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAGO0.png) and it works fine manually

but when I need to request for authorization from browser I can't read httponly cookies

Is there any way to handle this on server side

I configure the setting ti use crosheader for authorization header

Here is how I request in react application

**home component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {withCookies} from 'react-cookie';

export const Home = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Unauthenticated");
  useEffect(() => {

  (async () => {

  const response = await axios.get("user")//,{headers:{"Authorization":`Bearer`}}
  .then(() => {
        setMessage("hello user")
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers);
    
  });
  
  
  
})()
}, []);

return (
  <main>
    <h3 className="center">{message}</h3>
  </main>
);
};
```

***and here axios default setting in react app***

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

when I request that from browser I get 401 error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8pC3.png)

**LoginApiView endpoint**

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):

   @staticmethod
   def post(request):
       email = request.data['email']
       password = request.data['password']

       user = User.objects.filter(email = email).first()

       if user is None:
           raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid Credentials')

       if not user.check_password(password):
           raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid Credentials')

       access_token = create_access_token(user.id)
       refresh_token = create_refresh_token(user.id)

       UserToken.objects.create(
        user_id = user.id,
        token = refresh_token,
        expired_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    )
       responce = Response()
       responce.set_cookie(key = 'access_token', value = access_token, httponly=True) # secure= True
       responce.set_cookie(key = 'refresh_token', value = refresh_token, httponly=True) # secure= True
    
       responce.data = {
        'access_token':access_token,
        'refresh_token':refresh_token
       }
       return responce
```

**UserAPIView endpoint**

```
class UserApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        return Response(UserSerializer(request.user).data)
```

**userAPI middleware**

```
class JWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

        if auth and len(auth) == 2:
            token = auth[1].decode('utf-8')
            id = decode_access_token(token)

            user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
            return (user, None)

        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Unauthenticated")
```

any help will be appreciated, Thanks

**if there something unclear in my question please comment below**

Comment: what's the problem with your request

Comment: the request throw an error, I need a way to fix it

Comment: no need for a set cookie, you are building a REST/API so your client should accept data in the response and deal with it - you set a cookie is telling the client (browser) to manage the cookie

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Allam I need to logout the user if access token is expired is there a way without doing that

Comment: use server-side to track the tokens once the user hit the logout endpoint you block this token in Redis/db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could edit **userAPI middleware** this way

```
class JWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        if request.COOKIES['access_token']:
            id = decode_access_token(request.COOKIES['access_token'])
            user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
            return (user, None)

        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Unauthenticated")
```

hope it will work, just be sure you are passing the **cookies** in the request